# mapply giving non-numeric argument to binary operator error in R

Tags: r, mapply

I am trying to generate a variable flagging implausible age differences between respondents and their parents in a household roster. mapply() gives an error on "non-numeric argument to binary operator" while I don't get this error when I apply the function on only two columns. Any help is very much appreciated. Below, I tried to make a reproducible example.

```
# Variables
respbirth <- c(1974, 1950, 1990, 1980 ) 
B1010_1 <- c(1950, 1960, 1960, 1979 ) 
B1040_1 <- c(3,3,3,3)
B1010_2 <- c(1974, NA, NA, 1975 ) 
B1040_2 <- c(3,1,3,3)

# Data frame
df <- data.frame(respbirth, B1010_1, B1040_1, B1010_2, B1040_2 ) 
df

# Generate empty variable for flaging cases
df$flag_parent <- FALSE

## Generate a function flagging implausible differences using year of birth
attach(df)  # the function doesnt work without this for some reason
imp.parent <- function(data=df,parentAge=B1010_1,relationship=B1040_1) {
  df$flag_parent <- with(df, ((respbirth-parentAge)<18) & (relationship==3))
return(df)
}

# Test
df <- imp.parent(parentAge=B1010_1,relationship=B1040_1)

# Apply this function to all columns
parentAge <- c(paste0("B1010_",1:19, sep=""))
relationship <- c(paste0("B1040_",1:19, sep=""))
mapply(imp.parent, parentAge, relationship )
```

Comment: Why do you have `library(tidyverse)` here? Everything here is base.

Comment: `imp.parent` is not saving any changes, it is returning a numeric vector. If you intend for it to add a `flag_parent` to the frame and then return the frame, *you need to do that* (e.g., `df` or `return(df)` as the last line of the function).

Comment: You assign `logical` values to `flag_parent` initially but then in the function assign `numeric`. And then you complain about not assigning `TRUE` when it should. I'm really confused.

Comment: Thanks @r2evans, the first issue is resolved by assigning the function to df outside the function -- return(df) within the function didn't work. I  removed as.numeric() now which was added when I was experimenting. But actually it works either way and I get the same error for the mapply().

Comment: Odd, the way your function is written, this shouldn't work: `df` should be overwritten by a vector, losing all of the frame. The return value from `imp.parent` should be the value returned from the last expression in its body, which in this case is `with(df, (...))`. Even though that value is being stored as a column (preexisting or new) in `df$` does not matter, the value on the right side of the `<-` is a vector, which is what is getting returned by the function call. Or perhaps I'm missing something. (You are `attach`ing it earlier, which is generally bad for reasons like this.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there are numerous issues with your `mapply` attempt including parameter types, function call, returned values, and others. To avoid a long listing of those issues, consider the below re-factored code.

```
# Generate a function flagging implausible differences using year of birth
imp.parent <- function(parentAge, relationship, data=df) {    
  ((df$respbirth - df[[parentAge]]) < 18) & (df[[relationship]] == 3)  
}

# Apply this function to all columns
parentAge <- c(paste0("B1010_", 1:2))
relationship <- c(paste0("B1040_", 1:2))

# Assign columns True/False
df[paste0("false_flag_", 1:2)] <- mapply(imp.parent, parentAge, relationship )

df    
#   respbirth B1010_1 B1040_1 B1010_2 B1040_2 false_flag_1 false_flag_2
# 1      1974    1950       3    1974       3        FALSE         TRUE
# 2      1950    1960       3      NA       1         TRUE        FALSE
# 3      1990    1960       3      NA       3        FALSE           NA
# 4      1980    1979       3    1975       3         TRUE         TRUE
```

In fact, you do not even *need* `mapply` (hidden loop)! R can calculate the logical condition across equal length blocks of data for vectorized assignment of block of columns:

```
# Apply this function to all columns
parentAge <- c(paste0("B1010_", 1:2))
relationship <- c(paste0("B1040_", 1:2))

# NOTICE USE OF `[` (NOT `[[`)
df[paste0("false_flag_", 1:2)] <- ((df$respbirth - df[parentAge]) < 18) & (df[relationship] == 3) 

df    
#   respbirth B1010_1 B1040_1 B1010_2 B1040_2 false_flag_1 false_flag_2
# 1      1974    1950       3    1974       3        FALSE         TRUE
# 2      1950    1960       3      NA       1         TRUE        FALSE
# 3      1990    1960       3      NA       3        FALSE           NA
# 4      1980    1979       3    1975       3         TRUE         TRUE
```

<kbd>[Online Demo](https://rextester.com/DBUON46779)</kbd>

Comment: This is great, thank you very much! I have a lot to learn, and handling data types feels like one of the most tricky things. In Stata, I would have done this using for loops and locals, but I spend hours to do the same thing in R. It is a very different world.

Comment: Great to hear and glad to help!

Comment: I accepted the answer, cannot upvote - not enough popular yet :) Thanks again Parfait, you made my day!